# Prevent a byte from wrapping back to 0 when incremented over 255

Tags: c#, xna

I'm writing an XNA 3.1 application for a C#/XNA class I'm taking right now. It's a very simple introductory assignment where the user simply changes the color of the screen, pressing the R, G, or B buttons on the keyboard to choose a color channel and then the up and down arrows to increase or decrease the value of that channel.

If I increment a byte past `255` it wraps back to `0`, and vice versa for decrementing, presumably because C# actually converts a `byte` to an `int` when doing arithmetic on them. However, my professor specifically asks that once a channel reaches its maximum or minimum value that it stays there if the user tries to go out of these bounds. I figured out a way to fix this by myself, but I didn't find anything when I searched for solutions to this kind of problem on here or on Google. This is how I've solved the problem here:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    // ...

    Color color;

    private int Red
    {
        set { color.R = NoWrapIntToByte(value); }
        get { return (int)color.R; }
    }

    private int Green
    {
        set { color.G = NoWrapIntToByte(value); }
        get { return (int)color.G; }
    }

    private int Blue
    {
        set {color.B = NoWrapIntToByte(value); }
        get { return (int)color.B; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an integer to a byte but doesn't wrap.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static byte NoWrapIntToByte(int x)
    {
        if (x < Byte.MinValue)
            return Byte.MinValue;
        else if (x > Byte.MaxValue)
            return Byte.MaxValue;
        else
            return (byte)x;
    }
}
```

Every time the `Draw()` method is called, the color stored in `color` is set as the color of the screen.

Just for clarity, I realize I can't do something like

```
byte x = 256;    // compiler error
```

the compiler will complain. However, when the user presses the up or down arrows that color channel is incremented or decremented, and if the channel is decremented below 0 or incremented above 255 it will wrap. I used `int` as the type of the channel properties because if I'm using something like `Red -= 1` or `Red += 1` there are different expectations that happen if I go out of bounds. If I'm adding I would expect the resulting value to be smaller than the original value, and vice versa if I'm decrementing. I'm using `int` because it allows me to detect this in the property and handle accordingly.

I think my solution is okay, but I'm curious if I'm overlooking something. I can't be the only person who has tried to solve this problem so I'm curious what an idiomatic or best-practice way to solve this problem would be. I'm not asking for answers to my homework problem since I do already have a solution that works. However, I don't know C# that well so I'm curious if there's a much simpler way of doing this same thing, or with less code than what I have here. I'm aware that I can make C# throw an `Overflow` exception, but that requires changing project settings, and it also doesn't tell me specifically what kind.

Thanks!

Comment: byte x = 256 is too large for a byte, 255 would be the largest value, so the compiler is correct.  I think your solution is fine.  I would write it as an extension, but that is just me.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that the compiler will complain. Maybe I'll add a comment for clarity...

Comment: Why are you using `int` in the first place? Why not always use `byte`? That would avoid a lot of casting.

Comment: Because I have to know why the byte wrapped. If I go over 255, an integer will hold 256,. If I go under 0, an integer will hold -1. A byte throws that information away.

Comment: @Andrew oh, ok. Then, if I understand correctly, once you get a solution you're happy with, you'll use `byte`? Or is there some other constraint which requires an `int`?

Comment: @DonkeyMaster I don't know that there's anyway I could use `byte` and get a good solution. C# does all arithmetic on bytes by first converting them to integers. The signed `int` -1 when truncated to a `byte` is equal to 255 since in two's complement form it's all 1s, and then the first three bytes are truncated yielding `1111 1111`, or `255`. Once this happens there's no way to detect if I went over or under since it's always going to yield a byte value and I have no way of knowing if I just came from 0 or if the value has been incremented up to `255`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me that you should just be using the "Clamp" method built into the XNA framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.clamp.aspx

Basically if you want a value to say within 0 and 255 then you would just write something like this.

```
static byte NoWrapIntToByte(int x)
{
    return (byte)MathHelper.Clamp(x, 0, 255);
}
```

That should pretty much do exactly what it sounds like you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer seems like it ought to do what you want, but it feels like a lot of code to get there. If it were my problem to solve, I would probably do something more like this:

```
static byte NoWrapIntToByte(int x)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = Math.Max(x, 0);
    tmp = Math.Min(255, tmp);
    return (byte)tmp;
}
```

Thanks @Marlon for the `Math.Max/Min` fix.

Thanks @Andrew Noyes for the casting fix.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: you don't even know C# and you are an expert !! :P Math.Max and Math.Min are what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, your function is a bit simpler than mine, but they get the same result. I guess my real question is whether or not this function is necessary, like if there's a part of the language that allows me to do this without the function. Also, your return value in your function actually has to be cast to a byte in C#. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works but is fundamentally the wrong approach.  You should have written your property like this:

```
private int Red
{
    get { return (int)color.R; }
    set { 
        if (value < 0 || value > 255) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        color.R = (byte)value;
    }
}
```

Which lets anybody that uses your class, including yourself, fall into the pit of success.  After which you'd have found the proper solution, something similar to this:

```
private void IncrementRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.Color.Red < 255) this.Color.Red += 1;
}
```

You can then further improve this by having the property setter raise a PropertyChanged event.  An event you can subscribe in your UI to set the button's Enabled property to false so it is immediately obvious to the user that clicking the button is no longer useful.

Comment: I understand this approach completely, but the XNA workflow is different. There are no event handlers on button presses or anything of the like, it simply repeatedly polls the keyboard state, so it would be difficult to do something, admittedly more efficient (at least code wise, it's the same thing at the end of the day) like making the button "do nothing" once a certain game state is reached. I do understand your point about making the API such that it's always obvious what the right answer is when the user tries to do something that doesn't make sense. Good answer!

Comment: I just want to mention why I don't want to use a solution like this: the user can increment the value of the current channel both up and down, so when they press the up or down key a value from an `enum` called `Direction` is passed, either up (`1`) or down (`-1`). The increment operator is always used, but the value is positive or negative depending on the direction. Doing this with your solution would require two functions per channel, one for up the other for down, and a crap ton of conditional logic checking which is used.

Comment: Downvoted because you're throwing an exception for an event which should happen quite often.

Comment: @Donkey: that's a *property setter*, not an event.  You are very confused.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster I think the point of the exception is to allow the programmer to figure out what's wrong. Notice that in his event code Hans restricts the range of values that are passed to the setter to avoid throwing the exception in the first place. This is the fundamentally correct approach, even if it requires duplication of bounds-checking code any time the property is accessed. That's the reason why I accepted this answer.

Comment: @Hans: I'm going to give Donkey the benefit of the doubt and assume he was using "event" as an English word instead of a programming event.  That is, Donkey's concern is that the exception will be thrown frequently because the setter will be called with wrong values quite often.  Though that shouldn't be the case, for reasons Andrew has already discussed in his explanation for why he accepted your answer (rather than, e.g., sarnold's answer).  Personally, I like the idea that calling set,get sequentially will always yield matching values (or throw an exception).

Comment: @Hans and now I think I shouldn't have downvoted, because your `IncrementRed_Click`method works directly on bytes. Sorry about that. I think that your `IncrementRed_Click`, and a matching `DecrementRed_Click`, is a good enough answer. Wrapping getters and setters is adding unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to define a new structure wrapping a byte up in a set of overloaded operators and casters, like this.

```
struct NoWrapByte
{
    private byte _data;

    public NoWrapByte(byte data)
    {
        this._data = data;
    }

    public static NoWrapByte operator +(NoWrapByte a, NoWrapByte b)
    {
        if (a._data + b._data > 255)
            return new NoWrapByte((byte)255);
        else if (a._data + b._data < 0)
            return new NoWrapByte((byte)0);
        else
        return new NoWrapByte((byte)(a._data + b._data));
    }

    public static NoWrapByte operator -(NoWrapByte a, NoWrapByte b)
    {
        if (a._data - b._data > 255)
            return new NoWrapByte((byte)255);
        else if (a._data - b._data < 0)
            return new NoWrapByte((byte)0);
        else
            return new NoWrapByte((byte)(a._data - b._data));
    }

    public static implicit operator byte(NoWrapByte op)
    {
        return op._data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think i's possible to stop it from wrapping. You should use an int16 or an int32. However, you could use an if statement to check if the result would be larger than 255 and then convert it.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. `Color` is a class from XNA and `R`, `G`, and `B` are properties in that class and their type is `byte`. I can't change that, which is why I put these three properties in my own class.